# Как профилировать ЗАПУСК android приложения

Tags: android, производительность, профилирование

В чем собственно проблема. Стандартный traceview из android sdk требует ручного запуска и требует уже запущенной прилаги. Этого обычно хватает, но сейчас я начал замечать что у меня медленно стартует сама прилага. Т.е. от момента запуска до появления результата на экране проходит ощутимое количество времени. Особенно это заметно при запуске в отладчном режиме дело доходит до ANE иногда.

Ловкости моих рук не хватает чтобы одновременно запустить профилировку и прилагу одновременно.

Есть способ начать запустить прилагу одновременно с запуском профайлера?

Comment: я бы просто ручками добавил вывод в лог времени, затраченного на выполнение разных участков кода...

Answer (score 1):

если IDE Eclipse, то может быть создать отладочную конфигурацию типа launch group

Comment: Нет. У меня все в Android Studio. Но если развернете ответ то я подумаю как подобное в AS сделать.